# Watch folder and pull in data from CSV files

Tags: excel, vbscript

If I have an excel file, and I open that file, is it possible to check a folder on the system for CSV files and load them all in to mapped columns?

For example, we export report data every month. On month 1 there would be one file, on month 2 there would be two files, month 3, there'd be 3 files and so on. Each month the file might have a different number of rows, but the columns will be the same.

Is this possible to do natively in excel without vbscript?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand how to get effective help on SO. As written, this question is way to broad for this site.

Comment: Which part *specifically* are you having a problem with, and how have you tried to solve that?  Right now the only answer is "Yes" (it's possible to do what you want)

Comment: I just want someone to outline step by step what I need to do to accomplish this, and if there is some VBA script, help me write it or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible. Using the Shell() command you can open up the workbook you need to copy from, select the range necessary, and then copy the data into your master sheet.

All of this requiring that you be a little comfortable with VBA. If you're comfortable with Python, it is a little easier in my opinion to read the csv files in your folder and append your master file.

Comment: Can this be set up to automatically pull in all files when the MASTER is opened?

Comment: DV because this question should really never be answered as it's outside the scope for SO. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand how why.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, in multiple languages.

Just have your language of choice scan the folder on a timed job, load the file into memory, in an array, and then write the new file out, move the old file you've processed out into a "processed" folder.

I've been on manufacturing teams where they would send in batch orders for parts and we would process these from CSVs into system daily from a shared folder from multiple sales staff.  In PHP it was fread, fwrite.

To turn it into an Excel workbooks, there are packages/classes available for download online or if you Composer you can include them with your project.

Comment: Thanks I was looking more to do this in excel directly

Comment: DV because this question should really never be answered as it's outside the scope for SO. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand how why.

Comment: @W.A.Murray I actually don't think the site allows me to message your directly. I'm basically just looking for a step by step on how to do this, OR a VB Script that will do it. I'm not sure if excel supports languages like PHP, if it did, I could write it using that.